# memcached vs. database for random select

Tags: django, performance, design-patterns, memcached

I have a question about DB/memcached usage. I have a series of questions in database, divided by level (about 1000 questions per level). For each user at each step I need to select one question for specified level randomly. I use standard django's ORM select + random row using this query:

```
question = Question.objects.all().filter(level=1).order_by('?')[0]
```

After analysis of log files I saw that about 50% of all DB query time is spent on selections of questions. I tried to use memcached for it. Because of randomize choise it is not obvious, I can't use it like key-value storage for question_id-question pairs. So I decided to split questions by level, store them in memcached, after it select a group of questions from memcached and choose random one using python like this:

```
for level in ...:
    questions_by_level = [q for q in questions if q.level == level]
    cache.set('questions' + str(level), questions_by_level)
```

and when I need a question:

```
questions = cache.get('questions' + str(level))
question = choice(questions)
```

I have memcached on the same machine and geting 1000 questions this way is about 2.5 times slower, that from database. Probably it is because 1000 of objects is selectedfrom memcached, deserialized to python and random one is selected. 
Is it possible to choose another strategy for uing cache in this situation? Questions are updated rare, so it is a good lace to have a cache from my point of view.
Thanks.

**UPD**: one solution, that I discovered myself. For each question build a string key like this: l_n, where l is level and n is number of the question in the group of questions with level l. Now to find a random question I build a random key:

key = str(level) + '_' + str(int(random.random() * num_of_questions_by_level)

pros: getting of 1000 random questions is about 10 time faster, than from DB

cons: initial cache population is very slow

Comment: As I noted in my answer, the problem is your using memcached inefficiently.  Don't load all of the questions up front.  When you go to load a specific question with your random key first try to get it from cache, if its not there hit the database for that one question and put it into cache for the next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store them in the database with sequential id numbers and then simply pick a random number between 0 and the number of keys then check memcached for the key, if it returns the question use it if not pull it from the database and put it in memcached for the next use.

This will run you into problems if you delete questions and so there are missing IDs in the sequence but this problem can be overcome, for example, if instead of using IDs you instead select the X item in the database and then when the questions do change you clear memcached so the data gets refreshed.